# SendAsync using HttpClient in Xamarin Forms not awaiting

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I am busy developing a Xamarin forms application and have been struggling the last 2 days to get a successful post to my webApi from the application. Posting to the WebApi from the chrome Postman app works perfectly but I cannot seem to get it going from the application.

This is the webApi method that I am trying to call:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public string Authenticate(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string JsonObj = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        AuthToken _authToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthToken>(JsonObj);

    int UserID = DomainAuth.ValidateDomainAccount(_authToken.Username, _authToken.Password);

    if(UserID > 0)
    {
        _authToken.UserID = UserID;
        _authToken.Authenticated = true;
    }
    else
    {
        switch(UserID)
        {
            case -99:
                _authToken.AuthMessage = "The entered domain account does not exist";
                break;
            case -98:
                _authToken.AuthMessage = "The entered domain account does not have application access";
                break;
            case -97:
                _authToken.AuthMessage = "Incorrect username and password combination";
                break;
        }
    }

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_authToken);
}
```

I was originally trying to post to IIS Express but read on a post that this cannot be done when using an external device so the api is hosted in IIS now.

This is the method that my viewmodel command calls:

```
public async void Login()
        {
            Tuple<bool, string> AuthCheck = await _authService.AuthenticateDomainAccount(_username, _password);

            if (AuthCheck.Item1) //Item1: True / False value indicating if the login was a success
            {
                Helpers.Settings.Username = _username;
                await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("Synchronization");
            }
            else
            {
                FeedbackMsg = AuthCheck.Item2; // Item2: Message indicating why the login has failed.
            }
        }
```

And lastly this is the method that makes the api call:

```
 public async Task<Tuple<bool, string>> AuthenticateDomainAccount(string _Username, string _Password)
        {
            AuthToken _authToken = new AuthToken { Username = _Username, Password = _Password };

            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler, false))
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                using (HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "User/Authenticate"))
                {
                    req.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_authToken), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    try
                    {
                        var response = await client.SendAsync(req);
                        Debug.WriteLine("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ HERE I AM @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
                        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string a = "a";
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

When I step through the application it hits the SendAsync line, but instead of waiting for it to return as expected, it skips the lines below it and immediately returns null as per the final line of the method.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Can you check whether the WebAPI receives any request from your Xamarin app?

Comment: Put a print inside the exception block e.g. `Debug.WriteLine("exception calling SendAsync: "+ex.ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue over here is with the Uri you are trying to hit. SendAsync method may be throwing a 404 because of incorrect Url.

Please change the following line:

```
using (HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "User/Authenticate"))
```

to

```
using (HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/User/Authenticate"))
```

assuming your BaseAddress ends with a '/' at the end, else it will be

```
using (HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/User/Authenticate"))
```